# Iterating through NSArray with asynchronous block

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray

Not sure if this is the right title for this question or not..anyways,
I have an array of dictionaries and I am iterating through the dictionaries, passing in a block that gets executed sometimes in the future (asynchronous) and saving the result in a dictionary. Here's my method:

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info {

    NSLog(@"%@", info);
    NSMutableDictionary *images = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[info count]];

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in info) {
        NSURL *assetURL = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

        [library assetForURL:assetURL
                 resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)  {
                     NSString *filename = asset.defaultRepresentation.filename;
                     UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
                     [images setObject:filename forKey:image];
                 }
                failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                    [SVProgressHUD dismissWithError:@"Error occured."];
                }
         ];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", images);

    [library autorelease];
    [self dismissImagePickerVC];
}
```

Ofcourse, at the end of this method, images is empty, but my question is, how can I get a call back when all the blocks for each iteration has been executed?
Thansk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> When the enumeration is done, enumerationBlock is invoked with group set to nil.

When enumeration is done, your first block will see `asset == nil`.

Comment: @PragmaOnce You *find* assets by *enumerating* through them using `ALAssetsLibrary`. Of course you can store them in a container of your choice to iterate through them again if you wish. You can also make a callback once you see `nil`, and count their number in the block. Once the number reaches the number of items in the dictionary, you know that all callbacks have finished.